# I am working on a website project where a user can add its property ads.I want to show numbers of views of the particular ad.like OLX does .

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analytics. In my project One user has multiple ads and I want to show the numbers of views of each ad at top of it.How I can get numbers of views from google analytics of each ad and show them to the visitor??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).

Comment: I am using  Google Analytics Reporting API but I am just beginner with it.There are two files(index.php, oauth2callback.php) given at the official page of API, but i dont know where to place them and how to test them in LARAVEL .If anybody knows then kindly guide me.Thanks in advance